# Component<{}, {}, State>. What is this Syntax in React?

Tags: syntax, reactjs, flux

I am going over Flux Utils TodoMVC example (from [Flux GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-utils-todomvc) site) and is confused over the following syntax (code brevity here) present in [TodoApp.react.js](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/b8fd975218245ff6ed72defa9e881ac03853b7ed/examples/flux-utils-todomvc/js/components/TodoApp.react.js#L35) file

```
class TodoApp extends Component<{}, {}, State> {
 //  ...
 // ....................
}
```

What does this syntax tell us?

Comment: Can you point to the exact file URL?

Comment: Why would they use TS while Facebook is promoting Flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Bounded Polymorphism (generics)](http://flowtype.org/blog/2015/03/12/Bounded-Polymorphism.html), a feature from [FlowType](http://flowtype.org/), which Facebook is using on its Flux examples.

Flow files will all have a `@flow` annotation at the top.

Comment: But it is inheriting here from Component class. As per reading after your provided Flow link, the Component class should be somewhat like: ```Component<T: { x: object }, Y: { y: object }, Z: { z: object }>```. 
Am I right?

Comment: @Faisal Yes that makes sense, but I just can't find anyware the list of generic parameters for the Component class. :(. But yes, it should be 3 generic arguments

Comment: That's also perplexed me.  Facebook's documentation is quite confusing and/or incomplete at various places.

Comment: @FaisalMq Agreed. Anyway, check this out, it's cool: http://reactcheatsheet.com/ :)

Comment: Well that link still does not explain our primary headache.......the Component class.